# How can handle 500 error? ft. flask, pyjwt

Tags: python, jquery, jwt

I am studying to make a login function using a token in a flask. But, it runs well on the local server, but there is a 500 error when I turn it on awsec2. Help me.
The line "token = jwt.encode(payload, SECRET_KEY, algorithm ='HS256')" causes 500 error
app.py

```
@app.route('/admin', methods=['POST'])
def loginAdmin():
    name = request.form['name']
    password = request.form['password']
    pw_hash = hashlib.sha256(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    user = db_user.find_one({'name':name, 'password': pw_hash})
    if user:
        payload = {
            'name' : name,
            'exp' : datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=100)
        }
        token = jwt.encode(payload, SECRET_KEY, algorithm = 'HS256')
        # return jsonify({'as':token})
        return jsonify({'result':'success', 'token': token})
    else:
        return jsonify({'result' : 'fail', 'msg':'check id or pw'})
```

front

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            })
            function getcookie() {
                console.log('asdf')
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/admin",
                    data: { name: $('#name').val(), password: $('#password').val() },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response['result'] == 'success') {
                            $.cookie('mytoken', response['token']);
                            alert('로그인 완료!')
                            window.location.href = '/'
                        } else {
                            alert(response['msg'])
                        }

                    }
                })
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put a try - except around the line that you think causes the error, like this:

```
try:
    token = jwt.encode(payload, SECRET_KEY, algorithm = 'HS256')
except Exceptions as error:
    error_text = repr(error)
    print(error_text)
```

you can even return this error to the client (but this is not recommended for production code).

```
return jsonify({'result' : 'error', 'error_message': error_text})
```

It seems you're having problems debugging your code, this is more like a debug-alternative. I'd recommend using an IDE that lets you step through the code line by line. Just getting a 500 error doesn't help you - or us - very much

but I think your payload isnt valid, you're giving it a datetime object, which the encode function can't handle.

```
TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

convert this to a string or unix timestamp first and try again

```
payload = {
        'name' : name,
        'exp' : str(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=100))
    }
```

or as a UNIX timestamp:

```
import calendar
time_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=100)
unix_timestamp = calendar.timegm(time_now.utctimetuple())

payload = {
        'name' : name,
        'exp' : unix_timestamp
    }
```

Or if you get a NameError, that would indicate you're missing the SECRET_KEY, could be a configuration error